# Scikit Learn - ValueError: X has 26879 features per sample; expecting 7087

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am doing feature selection by first training LogisticRegression with L1 penalty and then using the reduced feature set to re-train the model using L2 penalty. Now, when I try to predict test data, the transform() done on it results in a different dimensional array. I am confused as to how to re-size the test data to be able to predict.

Appreciate any help. Thank you.

```
vectorizer = CountVectorizer()
output = vectorizer.fit_transform(train_data)
output_test = vectorizer.transform(test_data)

logistic = LogisticRegression(penalty = "l1")
logistic.fit(output, train_labels)
predictions = logistic.predict(output_test)

logistic = LogisticRegression(penalty = "l2", C = i + 1)
output = logistic.fit_transform(output, train_labels)
predictions = logistic.predict(output_test)
```

The following error message is shown resulting from the last predict line. Original number of features is 26879:

```
ValueError: X has 26879 features per sample; expecting 7087
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There seem to be a couple of things wrong here.
Firstly, I suggest you give different names to the two logistic models, as you need both to make a prediction.
In you code, you never call the transform of the l1 logistic regression, which is not what you say you want to do.
What you should be doing is

```
l1_logreg = LogisticRegression(penalty="l1")
l1_logreg.fit(output, train_labels)
out_reduced = l1_logreg.transform(out)
out_reduced_test = l1_logreg.transform(out_test)
l2_logreg = LogisticRegression(penalty="l2")
l2_logreg.fit(out_reduced, train_labels)
pedictions = l2_logreg.predict(out_reduced_test)
```

or

```
pipe = make_pipeline(CountVectorizer(), LogisticRegression(penalty="l1"),
                     LogisticRegression(penalty="l2"))
pipe.fit(train_data, train_labels)
preditions = pipe.predict(test_data)
```

FYI I wouldn't expect that to work better than just doing l2 logreg. Also you could try SGDClassifier(penalty="elasticnet").